# Is there a possibility to determine/restrict smart-contract addresses that can use the Chainlink Oracle Node I created?

Tags: chainlink

Is there a possibility to determine/restrict smart-contract addresses that can use the Chainlink Oracle Node I created? How can I ensure that only Smart Contract addresses that I set use my Oracle node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ease of convenience, you can restrict/whitelist by requesting smart contract addresses in the form of an array within the job-spec.toml found within the Chainlink GUI (localhost:6688). Below is from the docs [[here]](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/oracle-jobs/job-types/direct_request).

```
requesters = [
   "0xaaaa1F8ee20f5565510B84f9353F1E333E753B7a",
   "0xbbbb70F0e81C6F3430dfdC9fa02fB22BdD818C4e"
]
```